# Copy Rotation causes rigged foot to rotate the wrong way

Tags: rigging, bones

I've been following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVHKBSknFhA

My character's foot seems to roll to the left, instead of down, when **footRollCtrl.L** *(selected bone under Example)* is rotated down.

**Example:**
[image]

**Bones settings:**
[image]

Comment: What if you change the Space to: Local Space instead of World space?

Comment: @LeoNas all of them except for the IK bone use Local Space. I tried switching IK bone to Local Space, but the result is the same except that the whole foot moves up and down(toes don't stay on the "ground").

Comment: @LeoNas I think I got it. footRollCtrl.L bone had its axis messed up compared to other bones. I just rotated it to match other bones' rotation transform axis and it seems to behave now. Too see that I had to switch Transform Orientation from Global to Local.

Answer (score 0):

Axis were mismatching. Rotated the bone with wrong axis to match the rest and it works now.